# How to make a mesh within rectangle using drawing functions of the OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, colors, mesh, hsv

This is my full code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

width = cap.get(3)  # float
height = cap.get(4)  # float
print (width, height)

while (1):
    _, img = cap.read()

    if _ is True:
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    else:
        continue
    # blue color

    blue_lower = np.array([86,0,90], np.uint8)
    blue_upper = np.array([163, 64, 145], np.uint8)
    blue = cv2.inRange(hsv, blue_lower, blue_upper)
    kernal = np.ones((9, 9), "uint8")
    blue = cv2.dilate(blue, kernal)
    res_blue = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=blue)

            # Tracking blue
    (_, contours, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(blue, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if (area > 2000):
            print (area)
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(img, "Blue Colour", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (255, 0, 0))

            # cv2.putText(img, "Blue Colour", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (255, 0, 0))
    cv2.imshow("Color Tracking", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

I would like to mesh all rectangles as these pictures.
you can see the mesh of the contour next to them.
In my case, I would like to mesh rectangles themselves.
[image]

This picture is taken from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZkDxUnRg2g)

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-make-a-mesh-within-rectangle-using-drawing-functions-of-the-opencv/6037

Comment: yes. it is the same question.